# Nancy redirect to route under the current module

Tags: nancy

I need to redirect to a path under the current module:

```
modulePath = "/test";  
Get["/there"] = ...  
Get["/here"] = routeParams => { return ????????????("/there"); }
```

I expect "/test/here" to redirect to "/test/there"

Comment: `return Response.AsRedirect("/test/there");`

Comment: is it possible to do it without specifying the module path? ("/test")

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: @Phill could you put that as an answer so it could be marked? (rather than as a comment)

Answer (score 12):

You can use named routes and Nancy.Linker. See https://github.com/horsdal/Nancy.Linker

That is install `Nancy.Linker` from NuGet, take a dependency on `IResourceLinker` and change the code to:

```
public class YourModule
{
    public YourModule(IResourceLinker linker)
    {
        Get["theRoute", "/there"] = ...  
        Get["/here"] = Response.AsRedirect(linker.BuildAbsoluteUri(this.Context, "theRoute");
    }
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use my BaseModule. It will let you organise your web app into loosely coupled units, with related elements in the same folder: modules, views, static resources. This is achieved by registering the module's namespace (shorn of project name) as 1) the modulePath, 2) a search location for views and 3) a permissible location for static content.

As such, you go (back) to having URLs that map to the folder structure of your project. Items you're likely to work on together, and delete together, live together. Constructing links to things is greatly simplified. So for your redirect, you would have a folder structure

```
here
|-module.cs
|-there
   |-module.cs
```

and in your "here" module you just `return Response.AsRedirect("there/");`
For this to work, modules should inherit from the following BaseModule, and don't change the default namespace of your modules. It maps to the folder.

```
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Conventions;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HaciendaTestClient
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287636/pass-current-object-type-into-base-constructor-call
    public abstract class BaseModule<T> : NancyModule, IConvention
    {
        // the goal is to provide the folder path from the app root as the module path, to enable relative links to static content.
        public BaseModule() : base(typeof(T).Namespace.Substring(typeof(T).Namespace.IndexOf('.')).Replace('.', '/'))
        {
        }

        public void Initialise(NancyConventions conventions)
        {
            // This is where we register the top level directory containing the module as a root for static content.
            var tlf = Regex.Match(typeof(T).Namespace, "(?<=\\.)[^\\.]*", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
            var conv = StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory(tlf);
            conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(conv);
        }

        public Tuple<bool, string> Validate(NancyConventions conventions)
        {
            return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "no problem joe");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a little screenshot of my solution explorer, to get you interested. Since everything is called with relative links, everything can be called "_". The location becomes the identifier. And it's not brittle. Folders can be moved, renamed and nested. Just pay attention that the namespaces correspond! Nancy rocks.

[image]